# Why does IE8 render my site then immediately redirect to its internal 404?

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer-8, http-status-code-404

I administer a site, hosted on Yahoo! hosting, which has recently shown a strange behavior: when you visit in IE8, the page loads and is rendered normally, then as soon as it finishes rendering, the browser switches to show its local/internal 404 page.  The address bar still shows the site URL.

When I view the site in (as far as I can tell) the same state on my local Apache server, it doesn't do this.  This leads me to suspect it may have something to do with server configuration and response headers, but I don't know what that might be.

Is anyone familiar with this behavior?

Comment: It only happens in IE?  Not Firefox?  Can you share the URL for others to test?

Comment: Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to diagnose the problem better if possible (is there an in-browser tool like firebug for IE?). I suspect there is a secondary issue that is occurring such as changing the document href from javascript or using a funny META tag. Perhaps there is a (broken) "frame break" attempt or similar. Without providing source, best I can offer is to carefully inspect the the *actual* HTML and headers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I experienced this behavior when using a .htc hack to provide artificial CSS border-radius support.

Comment: Yes!  Sorry, I seem to have abandoned this thread, but it turned out to be this.  I was using an IE pngfix CSS behavior: call to an htc script.  Removing this fixed it (I now have a conditionally-commented JS solution to the PNG issue which fires after DOM loading, so no issue).

Comment: Had the same issue on a site I was working on - this bugger css: behavior: url("/scripts/csshover.htc");

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is causing that issue specifically, but you could use a packet capture utility like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.sourceforge.net/) or [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to investigate the issue further.  Otherwise, it would be helpful if you were to post a link to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your page contains JavaScript code which modifies the DOM while the page is still loading.

See other SO questions, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267160/what-is-the-operation-aborted-error-in-internet-explorer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266585/why-does-asp-net-cause-the-operation-aborted-error-in-ie7).

Solution: place your DOM manipulation code into < body onload> or jquery.ready() to execute after page loading is complete.