# What is wrong with this Javascript? "Internet Explorer Cannot Open the Internet Site- Operation Aborted" Error

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I put this javascript in the page it causes [this error](http://software-testing-zone.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/howto-fix-ie7-operation-aborted-error.html) in IE7 or IE8 and I have no idea what is wrong with it, at first it was in the head area of the page but I later moved it to after the body tag and added the defer=defer after some googling.

If I remove the JavaScript it all works fine.

```
<form name="myform" method ="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<table border="0" width="600px">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"/></td>
    <td>Company:</td>
    <td><input name="company" type="text" id="company"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email Address:</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"/></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="I Agree" name="myradiobutton" />
    I Agree</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="I Disagree"  name="myradiobutton" />
I Disagree</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submitit"" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
  </body>
  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the `valbutton()` function called from the submit button's `onClick="valbutton(myform);"`?

Comment: Does the error occur if you simply have `<script></script>` in your page?

Comment: does your page have any flash on it? looks like all of the issues causing this error are related to adobe flash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does ASP.NET cause the "Operation Aborted" Error in IE7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266585/why-does-asp-net-cause-the-operation-aborted-error-in-ie7)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem could be related to using the defer attribute without providing a corresponding src attribute in your js.

Try putting validateForm() into a script called validate.js or something, then use

```
<script defer="defer" src="validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[This post has more information and additional links on IE/defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

Comment: Yes, I believe defer is for linked scripts only. In any case, defer is a bit of a relic. There are better, more elegant ways these days of achieving the same thing.